# how to get a particular date by clicking the respective event(dow) in fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, fullcalendar

I am trying this

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({ 
      events:[{
          title:"events",
          dow: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
       },]
```

in this code how to get date like

`element.bind('click', function() { $('#pick_date').val(event.date);});`

Note: here there is no start date or range so how to get date when click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried eventClick?

[Event Click Documentation](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/)

```
    eventClick: function (event, jsEvent, view) {
       console.log('Event Start: ' + event.start.toISOString());
    }
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/jawumi/edit?js,console,output)

Answer (score 1):

Try to initialize the full calendar like this

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) { 
            alert('Clicked on: ' + date.getDate()+"/"+date.getMonth()+"/"+date.getFullYear());  
        }

});
```

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Ya I am checked, Hey getDate shows current date but I want to show event date when cliks on dow event.

Comment: Modified the answer

Comment: dayClick only works on click on day only  but I want to click on event then show  event date .That event have no start date because it is dow events

Comment: On Clicking the date u can check for any event is there for the clicked date, if the clicked date has event show alert/popup based on your requirement. If doesn't have it, don't show anything.